# How to export query result to csv file?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, export-to-csv

Is it possible to create csv file from this?

this table in database look like the one echo below

> ```
>     id  | category|  supplier   | price
>     1   |    A    |  supplier1  | 5
>     2   |    B    |  supplier2  | 3
>     3   |    B    |  supplier1  | 7
>     4   |    C    |  supplier3  | 6
>     5   |    C    |  supplier1  | 2
>     6   |    B    |  supplier3  | 9
> ```

```
<?php
session_start();
$host = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$pass = "";

$con = mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass);
if($con)
{
      $db = mysql_select_db('stocks');
       if($db)
       {}
       else 
       {
         echo "No Database Found! " ;
        }
}
else 
{
     echo "Failed to Connect! ";
}
?>
<table>
<tr>
    <th>Category</th>
    <th>Stock</th>
    <th>Percentage</th>
</tr>
<?php
$total=6;
        $q="SELECT id,name,supplier,price,COUNT(*) FROM  items GROUP BY supplier";
        $r = mysql_query($q);
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($r))
        {
                 $ratio=($row['COUNT(*)']/$total)*(100);
            echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['category'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['COUNT(*)'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . round($ratio,2). "%</td>";
echo "</tr>";
        }
echo "</table>";        
         ?>
```

How can I put that in csv?

I only know to do it for select all in table.

Category Stock   Percentage
     A       1       16.67%
     B       3       50%
     C       2       33.33%

Comment: @ using toad for oracle you can do it .. is that option help you if yes ill tell you how to do it

Comment: @Gordon thank you but i'm new to programming just stumbled table-csv topic and i wonder if it can do this too would be very useful in the way

Answer (score 1):

You can use php function fputcsv for this. i am sharing a example working code.

```
$output = fopen('result.csv', 'w');

$rs=mysql_query($sql,$conn);

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs)) {
    fputcsv($output, $row);
}
```

Comment: it works but it output everything in database how to make it look like the above echo

Answer (score 0):

```
// output headers so that the file is downloaded rather than displayed
header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=data.csv');

// create a file pointer connected to the output stream
$output = fopen('php://output', 'w');

// output the column headings
fputcsv($output, array('Column 1', 'Column 2', 'Column 3'));

// fetch the data
mysql_connect('localhost', 'username', 'password');
mysql_select_db('database');
$rows = mysql_query('SELECT field1,field2,field3 FROM table');

// loop over the rows, outputting them
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rows)) fputcsv($output, $row);
```

link to the page http://code.stephenmorley.org/php/creating-downloadable-csv-files/   hope that fit your needs

Comment: but  $ratio is not in database table? ok i will try i hope it does

Comment: it outputs everything in table

Comment: use isnull(column_name,'0') as column_name in select query for handle nulls and that's the final tip to remove errors enjoy

Answer (score 0):

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($r))
        {   $data=array($row['category'],$row['COUNT(*)'],round(($row['COUNT(*)']/$total)*(100),2));
            fputcsv($output, $data);
        }
```

@Davinder @Virgilio this works exactly thanks but with error message (Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ')' in C:\xampp\htdocs\revamp\csv.php on line 39)
other than that it works perfectly